# Reading Two Dimensional array from text file

Tags: c#, arrays

What I am doing is reading in from a text file, and then storing the contents in a 2D array, but my array is off by one at each row and column.  Maybe this is simple and I am just not seeing it?

The contents of my text file:

```
0007,0007,0007,0007,0007,
0007,0007,0007,0007,0007,
0007,0007,0007,0007,0007,
0007,0007,0007,1707,0007,
0007,0007,0007,0007,0401
```

When my array is returned, the value `17` is located at `[3,3]`...it should be `[4,4]`.  Below is my code. I've spent to much time on this already, could someone please help?

```
public int[,] Generate(string inputFilePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(inputFilePath))
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> counts = GetRowAndColumnCounts(inputFilePath);

        int rowCount = counts["row_count"];
        int columnCount = counts["column_count"];

        returnArray = new int[rowCount, columnCount];

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(inputFilePath))
        {
            string s = "";
            string[] split = null;

            for (int i = 0; (s = sr.ReadLine()) != null; i++)
            {
                split = s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    returnArray[i, j] = int.Parse(split[j].Substring(0,2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // throw new FileDoesNotExistException("Input file does not exist");
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: From where I see it, the result is fine. Array indexes start at 0, not 1 , so `1707` which is on the 4th line and 4th column is actually at index 3,3.

Comment: 1 based indexes are the devil. Repeat that every night and morning.

Comment: OF course I knew that the arrays are zero based. But thank you for confirming the code was correct. Turns out that this wasn't the offending piece of code after all for the issue I was having.  Its all good now that Ive tracked down the real issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes start at 0. So index 3 is the 4. element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

> C# arrays are zero indexed; that is, the array indexes start at **zero**.